# Alternative API Token for Controller When Using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I have devise token_auth working fine in my rails 3.2 application. I'm just building an API and need to override the devise authentication mechanism with another token. Why? Because one user has many locations and I want to provide independent access via this token to each location without compromising the whole account.

When a location is created, a location api_token is automatically created.

In my locations controller that I'm trying to access with the new key, I have tried this:

```
class Api::V1::LocationsController  < ApplicationController 

  before_filter :restrict_access, :only => :index


  def index
      @locations = Location.all
      @page_title = "Locations"
      @page_title_content = "A list of all your locations. Click to customise and view reports"

     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @locations }
       format.xml { render xml: @locations }
     end
   end


   private

   def restrict_access
     api_key = Location.find_by_api_token(params[:access_token])
     head :unauthorized unless api_key
    end

end
```

Everything routes fine however, even when I'm not logged in and don't pass the key in the url, I am permitted to see all locations.

Any suggestions how I can get this working? Also, how can I restrict the locations seen to those with access? Usually I use cancan but can't see how this might work.

Answer (score 0):

With devise you need to use `:token_authenticatable` and override `find_for_token_authentication`. Here's what works in my app.

```
class User
  devise :token_authenticatable

  self.token_authentication_key = "access_token"

  def self.find_for_token_authentication conditions
    grant = AccessGrant.where(access_token: conditions[token_authentication_key]).
                         any_of({access_token_expires_at: nil}, {:access_token_expires_at.gt => Time.now}).
                         first

    if grant
      user = User.where(_id: grant.user_id).first
      user.current_grant = grant if user
      user
    end
  end
end
```

And after that you just call the standard `authenticate_user!` in a before filter

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  # don't protect from forgery here
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: Does that work in combination with the standard devise auth? I still need users with their devise token to login. S

Comment: In this app there's only token auth. But it should work with standard db auth too.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure I can see how the two would work together. I'll have a play in a minute. Thanks for help s

Comment: sorry for late reply. Have been having a play with this and can't seem to work. I still need separate token_auth for my users on top of being able give them a token for the separate model.